# Applications installed from Microsoft store does not launch with system startup as expected

Tags: boot, windows-11, windows-store-app, windows-store, application-launch

I have multiple applications installed from the Microsoft store with the “start on system startup” option enabled.

The applications actually don't launch on system startup. Regular Win32 Applications launch as expected at system startup.

I am using Windows 11 22H2 22621.1265.

Things I considered:

1. Clearing the cache of the Microsoft store.
2. Updating Windows 11 to the latest version.
3. Checking the Task Manager for startup entries.
4. Starting the Application Identity service.
5. I run the windows store applications troubleshooter did not solve my problem unfortunately.
6. I’m encountering the issue in MagicPods + Twinkle Tray + EarTrumpet + Intel Unison (All the Microsoft store applications installed in my device).
   [image: Applications installed from Microsoft store does not launch with system startup as expected]

Comment: Where do you see that it didn't startup? Do you have its icon in the traybar? Is it enabled in *Settings > Apps > Startup > Startup Apps*?

Comment: I do not see the app icon or the process in task manager.

Comment: Strange that the app offers an option that doesn't work. Try perhaps to uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: Multiple applications have the same behavior.

Comment: Could you a give a list of these applications (in your post)? Perhaps someone would have already encountered this problem with one of the apps.

Comment: Indeed. I’m encountering the issue in MagicPods + Twinkle Tray + EarTrumpet + Intel Unison.

Comment: Also an issue for me with EarTrumpet in Windows 11 23H2, and the suggested registry keys in @harrymc's answer are already configured like that by default.

Answer (score 0):

For EarTrumpet at least, I found that this is a known problem in this
bug-report:
[EarTrumpet isn't starting on boot on Windows 10 #468](https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet/issues/468).

The solution there was to run the following `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableFullTrustStartupTasks"=dword:00000002
"EnableUwpStartupTasks"=dword:00000002
"SupportFullTrustStartupTasks"=dword:00000001
"SupportUwpStartupTasks"=dword:00000001
```

This fix was validated as solving the problem by three participants
in the post, and was the reason that a moderator closed the issue
with the comment of: "This seems to be a popular Windows bug".
On my computer, these values are already set, so please check yours
before doing this.

Before running this `.reg` file, I suggest taking a backup of the
registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
by running `regedit`, navigating to the key and right-clicking it,
then choosing "Export". Creating a System Restore point would also
be a good idea before doing registry modifications.

Reboot after running the `.reg` file and check.

Comment: It didn’t work :(

Comment: Very disappointing for both of us...